# Creating a project with Django on windows 8.1

Tags: python, django, initialization, project

After successfully installed Python 3.4.2 and Django 1.7.1 on Windows 8.1,
I've been stucked by creating a project by initializing django-admin.py.
My path looks like:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

and got following AtrributeError:

```
from django.utils import timezone
File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 149, in <m
odule>
utc = pytz.utc if pytz else UTC()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utc'

C:\Users\thEpuQ8f\Dropbox\zephyrus>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: OK, installing pytz solved my problem. Now I have new one. I can't run the development server. Nothing happens when I run following command:

```
C:\Users\thEpuQ8f\Dropbox\zephyrus>mysite\manage.py runserver
```

It gets me only following message in the command line:

```
Usage: manage.py subcommand [options] [args]
```

What's wrong this time?

Comment: Try reinstalling pytz.

Comment: Based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/ try installing pytz,

Comment: Installing pytz helped, thanks.

Comment: Why not just navigate to the folder with `manage.py` and then use `python manage.py runserver`?